# NSNumberFormatter for degrees' values

Tags: swift, nsnumberformatter

Is there any proper implementation for  `0°00'00.00"` format?
`NSNumberFormatter` supports only `groupingSeparator` and  `decimalSeparator`.
Or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no degree-minute-second formatter in Foundation but it's not too hard to roll your own. Here's my crude attempt:

```
class DegreeFormatter : NumberFormatter {
    func string(from degree: Double) -> String {
        var remaining = degree

        let degree = remaining.rounded(.towardZero)
        remaining -= degree
        remaining *= 60.0

        let minute = remaining.rounded(.towardZero)
        remaining -= minute
        remaining *= 60

        let seconds = remaining

        return "\(Int(degree))°\(Int(minute))'\(self.string(from: seconds as NSNumber)!)"
    }
}

let formatter = DegreeFormatter()
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

print(formatter.string(from: 1.23456789)) // 1°14'4.44
```

You can customize it further to include custom degree symbols, whether to include the second, what units are allowed, etc.

Comment: `MeasurementFormatter` exists